# Trouble cloning Windows 7 Pro 64-bit to new, different hardware

Tags: windows-7

I would like to copy an OEM licensed copy of Windows 7 Pro 64-bit to a new machine.  I understand that the OEM license is tied to the original machine.  I just want to clone the old machine to a new machine - which has upgraded hardware - and then apply the OEM license for Windows 7 Pro 64-bit  that came with the new machine to the cloned OS.  Simple operation - licenses should be covered, and then I don't have to reinstall and reconfigure all of my apps.

Problem is, Windows gets a BSOD, probably because the installed drivers are not compatible, starting with the motherboard chipset and up to the video card, etc.  I need Windows to do a new hardware scan to pickup the new hardware.  I tried using devcon rescan from the cmd line, but it returned very quickly and did not seem to make any changes to the installed drivers.  I then tried using devcon remove * and still get the BSOD, but it looks different - although I cannot be sure because the BSOD flashes quickly and then the machine reboots.

Comment: Microsoft improved the success rate from what it was before the more modular Vista for people in your situation, and by 7 it was pretty high. So I have to wonder if there is some fundamental hardware difference like processor architecture (x86/x64, AMD/Intel, etc.)? Can you detail the hardware aspect a bit more? I think it could help your potential problem solver. Also, no need for parting phrases/signatures. You can edit that out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial is excellent:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/135077-windows-7-installation-transfer-new-computer.html

However, I had already imaged my drive, so I looked into Acronis TI Universal Restore.  It was not without issues - including the somewhat expected hunting for motherboard and hard disk drivers (which I thought would have been found on a standard Windows installation disk below Windows/inf - but which was not).  In any case, using a combination of Aronis Universal Restore followed by a sysprep on the new system seems to have done the job.  Even sysprep had issues however, and I needed to reboot to Safe Mode and then reboot to normal mode at one point (as described in the above tutorial) in order to get out of some endless reboot loop while setting up the devices.  Very strange.

In the end, sysprep did not let me / force me to re-activate my copy, so now I am concerned that I was not able to properly re-activate my new license, and I don't know how to trigger it to let me do so.  I want to keep the old machine as a backup machine, but now I have two machines running off one Windows license.

Finally, I preferred the above method over starting over with one of the direct methods in the tutorial (and as suggested by Matt above) because - while it also saved me the time of re-cloning my image - I also did not like the idea of running sysprep on the original machine, and needing to re config personal preferences and handle possible errors.  Also, Acronis states that sysprep may not work because issues with the hardware abstraction layer (HAL) setting and other low level issues may not get addressed.  I think I may have run into that issue given the manual driver supplementation I needed to to - but I can't be sure, perhaps Windows setup would have handled it.

The rebooting into Safe Mode tip in the tutorial in order to get sysprep unstuck saved me bigtime!

Answer (score 4):

*Windows gets a BSOD, probably because the installed drivers are not compatible* is correct. The OS is assuming other hardware is present and trying to use the current as it would the previous which, especially if the boards were different, cause it to BSOD.

I would recommend taking a backup of the machine first if you havent already but if you are moving to another system with different hardware you are looking at an imaging solution or something similar. One of the things that you could use, which is already on the computer, is sysprep. Typically located in `C:\Windows\System32\sysprep` one of its usable features is to force the computer to reinstall its drivers and remove unique details of the system for redeployment. It is typically used in an office environment for deploying *golden* images to a variety of computer makes/models. After closing all running software you could run a command like this on your computer. **BACKUP COMPUTER BEFORE YOU DO THIS**

```
sysprep /generalize /oobe /shutdown
```

After the computer is shut down clone it in that state. On the new machine the computer will reconfigure itself as best it can on the new hardware. More than likely you will need to install your own drivers but it should work. Also this will force you to register windows again which, again, should work.

More information on sysprep that would be *way* too much to include in this post can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc721940(v=ws.10).aspx). It is first and foremost part of a mass imaging deployment collection of tools but I think it would get the job done. One more thing: I can't find a reference for it but dont sysprep a machine multiple times. After the 3rd time you will have errors when the computer boots. If your sysprep fails restore from a previous clone that I recommended you to do.

Other solutions could include utilities like [Acronis](https://kb.acronis.com/content/1616) however I have not used any personally.

Comment: Thanks!  I did not mark as answer because I ended up taking a differnent approach based on where I was with my image and concerns about running sysprep on a machine that I wanted to keep in service.  Please see my reply below.

Answer (score 3):

Sysprep is the best way to do this but can be long-winded and a little difficult - A method I would try is on the new computer keep pressing F8 as it boots and select 'Disable automatic reboot' - When the blue screen appears rather than restart the computer will stop and display the error code and a message. This code is the only clue you are given as to why it won't boot.

One of the most popular causes of the blue screen during this procedure is stop 0x00000007B (only the last two digits are relevant) which is the SATA Hard disk drivers - If the code is this then change the SATA settings in the bios from IDE/Compatible to AHCI then restart.

If no joy then on the old machine use 'Windows Easy Transfer' to migrate all the settings and configuration from the old machine to the new - with the new machine having a fresh copy of Windows 7 64 bit which you have pre-confgured, but not installed the key.

Once you have used the key on the new machine windows should request that you call an automated key hotline which will then issue you a key for the new computer whilst invalidating the old.

If the old machine is intel and the new is AMD, then the only methods you can use successfully are Sysprep and Windows Easy Transfer.

Comment: My error code was stop 0x00000007B, but I checked the BIOS, and it was already set to AHCI, so this did not help me.  Thank you for the tip, but I ended up using a different approach, which I described above.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the 0000007B BSOD (related to SATA) then here is my working solution (IF your old machine is still bootable and not dead or dismantled).

I didn't fancy using sysprep and making a mincemeal of the user profiles. I also had tried Acronis True Image 2016 to no avail. Universal Restore didn't work in my unique case because the two platforms are drastically different (see below). Many generations of hardware apart, as well as old on IDE SATA and new on AHCI SATA. However, I tried something and it did work in the end so here it is.

As somebody mentioned above, it's usually 99.9% always related to the SATA drivers. This repair is a twist on guides I've seen when you want to change your BIOS settings from IDE to AHCI but you get the BSOD so you need to 'force' a SATA driver change in Windows before restarting with the BIOS change to AHCI.

Old comp - Core 2 Duo / Intel G35 Chipset / SATA in IDE/Ultra mode / Win764bit
New comp - Core i5 3rd Gen / Intel Z77 Chipset / Sata in AHCI mode

Firstly I did a quick bum install of Win7 on the new board with a few drivers, and what I found out to be probably the latest non problematic Intel RST setup that works on the 2nd/3rd gen Intel Z77 boards (12.9.0.1001). You can even use an older one, it won't matter because once you're successfully booted into your Windows on your new comp, you can install up the latest Intel RST that your platform supports. I also downloaded the F6 Floppy drivers related to this version off the Intel Download site. I then went into Device Manager and confirmed the exact AHCI driver to be the Intel 7 Series/C216 SATA AHCI Controller.

Then, I went back to the old computer, selected the current SATA driver in Device Manager (Intel ICH10 Ultra ATA Sata Controller, or something similar). I right clicked, and did a forceful driver update using the Have Disk option. I navigated to a pendrive holding the F6 Floppy drivers (downloaded in above step), and selected the exact driver as above - the Intel 7 Series/C216 AHCI Controller, in the list. It says driver incompatible but just force the update. When it asks to restart, don't restart. CLose all boxes. Shut down the computer.

Take the drive out (in my case the system SSD), stick it into the new computer and boot, and viola, you'll be back into your original Windows 7 installation. Uninstall old drivers (you can even do this on your old machine before commencing any of the SATA driver forced install), install up your new mobo drivers and you're good to go.

Hope this helps anyone with the 00000007B BSOD. All that's required is that you need to be able to see what SATA AHCI driver you have on your new platform you're trying to clone to. You can just do a quick barebone Win7 install on it like I did on a blank drive. Once you know exactly what the new platform requires, then the rest is a piece of cake. And you also are required to be able to still boot up off your old clone so this will only work if your old machine isn't mutilated or dead.

Hope this helps! This IS the solution to that BSOD so even if your old machine is dead, you should be able to boot your clone on a motherboard or machine that is the same generation of your duff machine, and the same SATA setting you had in the previous BIOS (IDE or AHCI). You just need to be able to boot into your clone to forcefully change the SATA driver to the newer one that matches your newer computer.